# MySQL-how can use count(*) for column data after splitting values with if statement in sql query?

Tags: mysql

My sql query is like below.

`select if(name like 'ram%',if(place = 'Chennai','ramChennai','ramUnknown'),name) as name,
count(*) as OwnerCount from detail where dept='CSE' group by name`

This query is splitting the name but counting is not happening correctly.
It is counting by old `name` `ram` and `raman` and not by `ramChennai` and `ramUnknown`

Is there any better way to count after splitting the column values?

Comment: provide source data and expected result please, your question is not 100% clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not understand what is your problem. Probably you should just set an alias `OwnerName` vs `as name` for calculated column to not confuse mysql server about naming:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23c61/1

```
SELECT
 IF(name LIKE 'ram%',IF(place = 'Chennai','ramChennai','ramUnknown'),name) as OwnerName,
 COUNT(*) as OwnerCount 
FROM detail 
WHERE dept='CSE' 
GROUP BY OwnerName
```

query works pretty fine